# Как работать с Grape?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

До этого реализовывал API только на Rails. Но сегодня наткнулся на Grape.

На GitHub странице есть базовый пример, в котором меня смутило использование моделей. Вот кусок кода:

```
desc 'Return a public timeline.'
get :public_timeline do
    Status.limit(20)
end
```

Ниже также становится ясно, что скорее всего это от фреймворков Sinatra или того же Rails, в который инегрируется Grape.

Но зачем, если на том же Rails можно реализовать хорошее API "из коробки"?

И что делать, если нужно реализовать чисто API, не имея Rails или Sinatra. Как быть тут с моделями и работой с БД?

Comment: Зачем? Если Rails уже вымораживает. Что делать? Определиться, что всё-таки есть. Если взять за основу Rack, то делать Rack handler/middleware любым удобным способом: классом с `initialize` и `call` или другим фреймворком или библиотекой. Работу с моделями и БД можно организовывать, опять же, любым удобным способом, любой ORM (или не ORM), можно даже взять рельсовый ActiveRecord. Тут довольно до фига рассказывать, определитесь, что именно вам нужно.

Comment: @D-side Зачем? Просто почитал и подумал, что если реализовывать чисто API, то лучше взять Grape. Но я так и не понял из документации, как реализовать взаимодействие с БД без фрэймворков. Поэтому и создал вопрос.

Comment: А как его реализует ActiveRecord? При старте достаёт из заданного места реквизиты для БД, создаёт пул соединений и всё. Дальше дело за AR.

Comment: Классы-модели AR пользуются уже созданным ранее пулом просто потому что наследуются от `ActiveRecord::Base`, хотя в них и можно явно указать другой. Но можно выкинуть и AR, пользоваться адаптером конкретной БД, например `pg`. Им достаточно просто пользоваться. Только удобные модели с его помощью сделать будет заметно сложнее.

Comment: Со слиянием Rails-API с Rails большой разницы делать API на Rails или на чём-то ещё технически уже нет. Так что выбирайте то, с чем вам проще работать (и на всякий случай посмотрите middleware stack на предмет лишних вещей). Пока вы привыкли к Rails, лучше используйте его. Как почувствуете, что он вам мешает, можете переходить.

Comment: @D-side хорошо. Спасибо за разъяснения.